# Doctrine ODM flush() with unique key

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine ODM to work with MongoDB. I have documents to save which can duplicate time to time. I need only 1 copy of each event, so I use hashed uniq key to ensure event is only 1.

So I do several ->persist($document);
And when I do ->flush();

I'm getting an exception:
localhost:27017: E11000 duplicate key error index: dbname.event.$eventKey_1 dup key: { : "keyValue" }

And all data never persisted to MongoDB. So question is: is any way to persist uniq data and ignore existing without doing:

```
try {
    ->persist();
    ->flush();
} catch (\Exception $e) {}
```

for each document?

Thank you.

**Updated:**
thanks for your answers and your time, but I found exact solution :)

Mongo function insert has an option "ordered: "
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/
which allow continue insertion even after errors.

Doctrine use Pecl extension for mongo.
doctrine flush() use this method:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php
which has option "continueOnError"

So if you do this way:

```
$documentManager->flush(null, ['continueOnError' => true]);
```

It will save all documents without errors and skip all with errors. Though it will throw "\MongoDuplicateKeyException". So all you need - catch this exception and handle or simply ignore it (depending on your needs).

Something like this :)

Comment: Before persisting you may try to find if there is already a document like this in the database and if it exists, just link to it instead of persisting it

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but idea was not to add additional queries. I believe should be some option just to ignore this exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The native Doctrine methods do not support filtering unique values - you need to do this on your own.
To insert those data without any errors you have to do a few things, depending on your entity structure:

1. Find all existing entities with the unique keys you have
2. Find unique keys that are duplicated between the entities you are trying to persist
3. Replace the already existing entities with the entities you found
4. Persist and flush

There is absolutely no chance to do this without at least one additionally query. If you had the primary key of the existing entities, you could use those to get a reference object. But unfortunately, there is no support for getting references by unique keys according to the doctrine documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys. Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the `['continueOnError' => true]` to work, so solved it differently:

```
$collection = $documentManager->getDocumentCollection(Content::class);
try {
    $collection->insertMany($arrayData, ['ordered' => false]);
} catch (BulkWriteException $exception) {
    // ignore duplicate key errors
    if (false === strpos($exception->getMessage(), 'E11000 duplicate key error')) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just do: Search your existing id edit it and save..

- **With Doctrine + symfony:**

  ```
  $Document = $EntityManager->getRepository("ExpBundle:Document")->find(123);
  $Document->setTitile("Doc");  
  $EntityManager->flush();
  ```
- **With Doctrine**

  ```
  $Document = $EntityManager->find('Document', 1234);  
  $Document->setTitle("edited");  
  $EntityManager->flush();
  ```